# Update Collection Value with Database in UWP(MVVM)

Tags: c#, mvvm, uwp

I have custom collection which contains `student_id`,`student_name`,`student_mark`.And having the table with same columns in the database as well. The design form have some controls for updating the existing student.

Temporarily all the updating operations are done with that custom collection.Lets assume we have 100 students data in collection and database. Any updating operation should reflect in the collection. But what my doubt is how do i update these values with the database before i close the application??

But when i open the application the collection should have all the values which have stored in the database.

Comment: What kind of database? How exactly do you use it?

Comment: mysql.. first i am adding students data to collection... and add the collections values to database. if i update the values in the collection the database values should also be updated. i am using the same collection for adding new values and retrieving the existing values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But what my doubt is how do i update these values with the database

Firstly, you need to know how to do `CRUD` operations on `MySQL` database with uwp app. For this, please reference [this sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Using-MySQL-database-with-03c1e9c7).

Secondly, according to your description, you have built up a `MVVM` project to bind a collection data to the view. But you didn't have a data layer for this `MVVM` structure. For this, you need to create a class for data layer to do `GRUD` operations, and establish contact with this data service from `ViewModel`. More details please reference [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/johnshews_blog/2015/09/09/a-minimal-mvvm-uwp-app/).

The class for data layer I wrote according to your description which contains how to read, update and delete data from `mysql` database is as follows:

```
public class Student
{
    public int Student_id { get; set; }
    public string Student_name { get; set; }
    public string Student_mark { get; set; }

}

public class DataService
{
    static string connectionString;
    public static String Name = "Data Service.";
    private static ObservableCollection<Student> _allStudents = new ObservableCollection<Student>();
    public static ObservableCollection<Student> GetStudents()
    {
        try
        {
            string server = "127.0.0.1";
            string database = "sakila";
            string user = "root";
            string pswd = "!QAZ2wsx";
            connectionString = "Server = " + server + ";database = " + database + ";uid = " + user + ";password = " + pswd + ";SslMode=None;";
            using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                MySqlCommand getCommand = connection.CreateCommand();
                getCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM student";
                using (MySqlDataReader reader = getCommand.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        _allStudents.Add(new Student() { Student_id = reader.GetInt32(0), Student_name = reader.GetString(1), Student_mark = reader.GetString(2) });
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (MySqlException sqlex)
        {
            // Handle it :)
        }
        return _allStudents;
    }

    public static bool InsertNewStudent(Student newStudent)
    {
        // Insert to the collection and update DB
        try
        {
            using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                MySqlCommand insertCommand = connection.CreateCommand();
                insertCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO student(student_id, student_name, student_mark)VALUES(@student_id, @student_name,@student_mark)";
                insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@student_id", newStudent.Student_id);
                insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@student_name", newStudent.Student_name);
                insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@student_mark", newStudent.Student_mark);
                insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();                   
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch (MySqlException sqlex)
        {
            return false;
        }

    }
    public static bool UpdateStudent(Student Student)
    { 
        try
        {
            using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                MySqlCommand insertCommand = connection.CreateCommand();
                insertCommand.CommandText = "Update student Set student_name= @student_name, student_mark=@student_mark Where student_id =@student_id";
                insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@student_id", Student.Student_id);
                insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@student_name", Student.Student_name);
                insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@student_mark", Student.Student_mark);
                insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch (MySqlException sqlex)
        {
            // Don't forget to handle it
            return false;
        }

    }

    public static bool Delete(Student Student)
    {
        try
        {
            using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                MySqlCommand insertCommand = connection.CreateCommand();
                insertCommand.CommandText = "Delete from sakila.student where student_id =@student_id";
                insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@student_id", Student.Student_id);
                insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch (MySqlException sqlex)
        {                
            return false;
        }
    } 
}
```

For updating the database in [`TwoWay`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.data.bindingmode) binding way, we can implement is by invoking the data updating method in 
[PropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.data.propertychangedeventhandler) event as follows:

```
  void Person_OnNotifyPropertyChanged(Object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
  {
      organization.Update((StudentViewModel)sender);
  }
```

For the completed demo you can download [here](https://github.com/sunteenwu/CMVVM).

Comment: Thanks @Sunteen Wu